# How to update column of each row with a substring value of another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to fetch the some value from column 'data_sent' and then updating column 'registry' with this value. But getting the issues.

Query below:

```
update can_data 
set registry = (SELECT cast(SUBSTR(split_part(data_sent, 
'registry&gt;', 2), 1, 26) as numeric) 
as registry FROM can_data);
```

SQL error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an
>   expression
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
>   SQL state: 21000

Comment: your subquery returns more than one record. i don't know your data, but if those values are equal, a DISITNCT in the subquery might help, if not you have to think about what you really want to set as new registry value - TOP 1 might be a dirty solution

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048955/postgres-error-more-than-one-row-returned-by-a-subquery-used-as-an-expression? It's kind of the same issue.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store computed values like that. (Will lead to data inconsistency.) Create a view instead.

Comment: yes I checked that solution but it doesn't apply here. I know that subquery is returning multiple rows but I need to apply all these rows to the outer query to update all rows.

Comment: why the (uncorrelated!) subquery? What is wrong with `update can_data 
set registry = cast(SUBSTR(split_part(data_sent, 
'registry&gt;', 2), 1, 26) as numeric);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery.  All you need is this:

```
set registry = cast(SUBSTR(split_part(data_sent, 
'registry&gt;', 2), 1, 26) as numeric
```

Comment: amazing..that is so simple.