# 500 Internal Server Error Given when Using PostgreSQL CONCAT Function

Tags: ajax, postgresql, codeigniter, concatenation

Base on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048955/postgres-error-more-than-one-row-returned-by-a-subquery-used-as-an-expression) finally can show result of query in phppgAdmin faster then before. Only add `LIMIT 1` after `PostgreSQL CONCAT` function make different about 5s which is from 7s to 2s.

This is my short sql:

```
$sql = "select tb1.*, 
(select name_code from master_code tb2 where tb2.code like CONCAT('%', tb1.code, '%') LIMIT 1) as master_code_name
from city tb1 where tb1.location_id like 'blablabla%'";
```

I use this script to show `city` based on `location_id`. One column of `city` contain code from `master_code`. **Actually, I just want to try to show the name of that column**. But when I try to load using `Model` and `Controller`, showing `500 Internal Server Error` in `console`.

**This is code in `Model`:**

```
  public function select_by_location(){

    $sql = "select tb1.*, (select name_code from master_code tb2 where tb2.code like CONCAT('%', tb1.code, '%') LIMIT 1) as master_code_name from city tb1 where tb1.location_id like 'blablabla%'";

        $data = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $data->result_array();
    }
```

**This is the Controller:**

```
 public function show() {
     $data['dataCity'] = $this->M_city->select_by_location();
     $this->load->view('city/list_data', $data);
 }
```

**Ajax:**

```
  function showCityAjax() {
    $.get('<?php echo base_url('City_controller/show'); ?>', function(data) {
        $('#data-city').html(data);
        refresh();
    });
  }
```

**Show result in:**

```
<div id="data-city"></div>
```

How to resolve this? Or is there another way to do it more efficiently. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you have in your model some kind of quotes, indicating string assignment? `$sql = "select tb1.*, (select stuff here ";`

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński sorry, I forgot add some quotes in my model at the question. I will edit it!