# Postgresql: Concatenate 2 columns data into 1 column

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I am migrating the data from one DB to another (both postgresql). I want to concatenate the value of firstname and lastname columns from the source DB to name column of the destination DB. When I try to run the query, I am getting an error: `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` Checking other threads here in SO, I found this [concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048955/postgres-error-more-than-one-row-returned-by-a-subquery-used-as-an-expression). I added LIMIT 1 to the code but it gives me the first and last name of the existing name in the table.

My code:

```
cur_t.execute("""
                SELECT firstname, lastname
                FROM authors;
                """)

for row in cur_t:
    cur_p.execute("""
                     INSERT INTO lib_author (
                                                 created, modified, last_name,
                                                 first_name, country,
                                                 school_id, name)
                    VALUES (current_timestamp, current_timestamp, %s, %s, %s,
                            (SELECT id FROM ed_school WHERE name='My Test School'),
                            (SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ',', last_name) AS name FROM lib_author LIMIT 1)
                            )
                    """, (row['lastname'], row['firstname'], ''))
```

How can I call the firstname and lastname column from the source DB?

Comment: something like `SELECT firstname || ',' || lastname FROM authors;`?

Comment: If you concatenate `first_name` and `last_name` like that, my name would appear as 'Mike,Sherrill'. I don't think you want that. I think you'd be better off building a *correct* `SELECT` statement, then just running `INSERT INTO lib_author SELECT . . . `. Good rule of thumb: if you're processing row by row in a SQL database, you're *probably* doing the Wrong Thing.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' what should be the best approach for migrating data. The data that I am migrating have inconsistencies that's while the destination DB have strict not null fields. Processing row by row gives me a bit of control on the data.

Comment: @JimJones Yes Jim, something like that. It's just that I am using 2 connections, cur_t and cur_p are different connections.

Comment: So I modified the code and removed `(SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ',', last_name) AS name FROM lib_author LIMIT 1)` and replaced it with `%s`. In the parenthesis with row values, I concatenated `(row['firstname'], row['lastname'])`. It works in saving the first and last name, problem is it includes the parenthesis. Any suggestions on how to remove the parenthesis?

Comment: Don't concatenate row constructors here. (Here `row()` is a row constructor.) Concatenate `firstname` and `lastname`. Start with `firstname || ' ' || lastname`. Nulls complicate things.