# In case-when-then-else clause gives ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression. in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, subquery, case-when

On firing below query gives an ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.

`select case when (table_name_1.column_name = 'ABC')` 
`then  (select column_name_2 from table_name_2 where column_name_3='XYZ')` 
 `else table_name_1.column_name end as result from table_name_1 ;`

Comment: The subquery `(select column_name_2 from table_name_2 where column_name_3='XYZ')` is returning more than one row. That's what you need to resolve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres Error: More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048955/postgres-error-more-than-one-row-returned-by-a-subquery-used-as-an-expression)

Comment: Look for a data integrity issue on table_2. There are at least 2 rows where column_name_3 contains the value "XYZ".  Questions to answer being "Is there a duplicate row?" or "Is there a predicate missing in the sub-select?"