# Postgres XMLCONCAT() with subqueries

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

I am trying to use Postgres to generate a single XML document as output.

Assume that I have a single relation, `customers`. It has the columns `id`, `name` and `email`.

I want XML that looks like this:

```xml
<customers>
    <customer>
        <id>0<id/>
        <name>Customer 1<name/>
        <email>customer1@gmail.com<email/>
    <customer/>
    <customer>
        <id>1<id/>
        <name>Customer 2<name/>
        <email>customer2@gmail.com<email/>
    <customer/>
    <!--and so on-->
<customers/>
```

So far, I can generate the XML for each customer, like this:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(NAME customer, 
           XMLELEMENT(NAME 'id', "id"),
           XMLELEMENT(NAME 'name', name), 
           XMLELEMENT(NAME email, email))
FROM customers;
```

However, concatenating this into a single XML document does not work. I have tried:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(NAME customers, XMLCONCAT((
    SELECT XMLELEMENT(NAME customer, 
               XMLELEMENT(NAME 'id', "id"),
               XMLELEMENT(NAME 'name', name), 
               XMLELEMENT(NAME email, email))
FROM customers;
)));
```

However, this fails with the message `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`.

Comment: You need to aggregate them. Since xmlagg is slow, you could do something like `SELECT XMLELEMENT(NAME customers, STRING_AGG(XMLELEMENT(NAME customer, XMLELEMENT(NAME 'id', "id"), ...)::TEXT, ',')::XML) FROM customers`

Comment: Refer to this link for the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048955/postgres-error-more-than-one-row-returned-by-a-subquery-used-as-an-expression

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of achieving this. An easy approach is to fetch the XML elements you want in a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) and aggregate them with [`xmlagg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html)

Sample Data

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE customers (id int, name text, email text);
INSERT INTO customers VALUES 
(0,'Customer 1','customer1@gmail.com'),
(0,'Customer 2','customer2@gmail.com');
```

Query

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT 
    XMLELEMENT(NAME customer, 
      XMLELEMENT(NAME id, id),
      XMLELEMENT(NAME name, name), 
      XMLELEMENT(NAME email, email)) AS customers
  FROM customers)
SELECT 
  XMLELEMENT(NAME customers, xmlagg(customers)) 
FROM j;

------------
<customers>
    <customer>
        <id>0</id>
        <name>Customer 1</name>
        <email>customer1@gmail.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <id>0</id>
        <name>Customer 2</name>
        <email>customer2@gmail.com</email>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

Another alternative is to use a subquery

```
SELECT 
  XMLELEMENT(NAME customers, xmlagg((customers)))
FROM (SELECT 
  XMLELEMENT(NAME customer, 
    XMLELEMENT(NAME id, id),
    XMLELEMENT(NAME name, name), 
    XMLELEMENT(NAME email, email)) AS customers
FROM customers) j;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add LIMIT 1 to the Subquery. This will remove the duplicate rows.