# Postgres more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

I don't understand what the problem is, I get this error:

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

```
select * 
from "History" 
WHERE "Message" LIKE '%' || (select "Name" 
                             from  public."Campaign"
                             where "Employ" IN (SELECT * 
                                                FROM (                                                                 
                                                  SELECT "Employ" 
                                                  FROM public."Sub"
                                                  where  "Company" ilike '%XX%'limit 1
                                                )
                                                union all
                                                (SELECT "Employ" 
                                                 FROM public."Sub"
                                                 where "Company" not ilike '%XX%'limit 1)
                                                ) as t)) || '%'
```

Comment: The query in  `LIKE '%' || (select...) || '%'` will probably return more than 1 row. The `LIKE` expects only 1 string with a pattern.

Comment: SQL Server and PostgrSQL are two different RDBMSs. Based on the syntax I suspect you are targeting PostgreSQL . Is this accurate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres Error: More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048955/postgres-error-more-than-one-row-returned-by-a-subquery-used-as-an-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to `LIKE` multiple names, it could `LIKE ANY` of the names.

```
select * 
from "History" 
where "Message" LIKE ANY (
     select '%'||"Name"||'%'
     from  public."Campaign"
     where "Employ" IN (
           (select "Employ" from public."Sub" 
            where "Company" ilike '%XX%' limit 1) 
           union all
           (select "Employ" from public."Sub"
            where "Company" not ilike '%XX%' limit 1)
     ) 
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I learned something new

Comment: Thx, I also learned something new. I wondered if the `ANY` operator would also function with the `LIKE` operator. Turned out it does.