# How to apply HAVING to a alias

Tags: sql, postgresql, having

I have query that creates a column on the fly like so:

```
SELECT 
v_list_client.id AS "id",
EXISTS(
  SELECT id FROM message 
  WHERE to_phone_number = v_list_client."phoneNumber" 
    AND  created_by_agent_id != 
  (SELECT id FROM agent WHERE agent_role_id = (
    SELECT id FROM agent_role WHERE label = 'Bot'))
) AS "hasReceivedMessageFromAgent",
*
FROM v_list_client
LEFT JOIN v_form
ON (v_form."client" ->> 'id')::integer = id
WHERE (v_form."formTypeId")::integer = 1
AND (v_form."isReceived")::boolean = true
HAVING "hasReceivedMessageFromAgent" = true
```

I'd like for the `HAVING` clause to only return results if the client has received a message from an agent, i.e if the `hasReceivedMessageFromAgent` column is `true`.

Comment: There is no aggregation happening in your query, so `HAVING` as a clause is inappropriate. Instead just add that condition to your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Yup thats it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HAVING` is only applicable after `GROUP BY`. But you also cannot refer to output columns in the `WHERE` clause. (That's what made you bark up the wrong tree.) See:

- [PostgreSQL Where count condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119489/postgresql-where-count-condition/8119815#8119815)

Drop the column `"hasReceivedMessageFromAgent"` from the result. By definition, it would always be true and hence noise. You really want to use the expression as filter in another `WHERE` clause.

I suspect more problems in your query. In particular the subquery on `agent` looks like it could return multiple rows, which would raise an exception. See:

- [Postgres Error: More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048955/postgres-error-more-than-one-row-returned-by-a-subquery-used-as-an-expression/21050919#21050919)

Consider this rewrite:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   v_list_client l
JOIN   v_form        f ON (f.client ->> 'id')::int = l.id  -- was a fake LEFT JOIN
WHERE  f."formTypeId"::int = 1  -- why the need to cast?
AND    f."isReceived"::boolean  -- why the need to cast?
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM message m
   LEFT   JOIN (agent a JOIN agent_role ar ON ar.label = 'Bot' AND ar.id = a.agent_role_id) ON a.id = m.created_by_agent_id
   WHERE  m.to_phone_number = l."phoneNumber" 
   AND    a.id IS NULL
   );
```

About the fake `LEFT JOIN`, See:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)

`"formTypeId"` should already be `integer`.
`"isReceived"` should already be `boolean`.
The cast for either is expensive nonsense. If the values are always valid, the columns should have the proper data type already. If not, the cast would fail.

Aside: If at all possible, use legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers in Postgres. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)