why I am getting syntax error when using select?
I get this error:
ERROR:  42601: syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 23:       ce.image from cars_images ce ON (c.id = ce.car_id)) as images

here is my code:
   SELECT

    c.id,
    c.model,
    c.description,
    c.environment,
    c.equipment,
    c.ps,
    c.tuv,
    c.cover,
    c.brand,
    c.price,
    c.engine,
    c.fuel,
    c.firstregistration,
    c.km,
    c.color,
    c.video,
    c.type,
    c.show,
    c.sit_place,
    (select
      ce.image from cars_images ce ON (c.id = ce.car_id)) as images
    
    FROM cars c


   GROUP BY c.id

   limit 100

what I am doing wrong on my subquery ?
I have googled but not found I saw the same subquery on others but idk why my it is not working

You are missing a join. Don't use ON without a join.
you probably want a WHERE instead
select
      ce.image from cars_images ce WHERE (c.id = ce.car_id)


now I got this error : more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

You need to correct the subquery to return only 1 row. You could add limit 1.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048955/postgres-error-more-than-one-row-returned-by-a-subquery-used-as-an-expression

.... which means the syntax error was solved. Google "scalar subquery" for an explanation of your new error message. You need to learn to read the error messages.

@emreayyildiz Or just use a normal join. It depends on what results you want: aggregation, or multiple rows per cars_image.

Your subquery is missing a join clause. on does not make sense without a join.
On the other hand, do keep in mind that in PostgreSQL to add a subquery in a select clause it must be a scalar subquery (it must return only one row). And query will be evaluated once per row (potentially slow).
You could try this:
SELECT
  c.id,
  c.model,
  c.description,
  c.environment,
  c.equipment,
  c.ps,
  c.tuv,
  c.cover,
  c.brand,
  c.price,
  c.engine,
  c.fuel,
  c.firstregistration,
  c.km,
  c.color,
  c.video,
  c.type,
  c.show,
  c.sit_place,
  (select STRING_AGG(ce.image, ', ') from cars_images where (c.id = ce.car_id)) as images    
FROM cars c
GROUP BY c.id
limit 100

